# Halmos: Inverse image implies function $X \to Y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the beginning of the Chapter on "Inverses and Composites," Halmos says: "A necessary and sufficient condition that $f$ map X onto Y is that the inverse image under $f$ of each non-empty subset of Y be a non-empty subset of X." and invites a proof.

I can see how the "necessary" part is true.  If there exists some $f$ where $\forall x \in X (f(x) \in Y)$, then there cannot exist some $B \subseteq Y$ where $f^{-1}(B)=\emptyset$ or, by definition, there would exist some $x$ where $f(x) \notin Y$.

But I'm struggling a little with the "sufficient" part.  How can you prove that just because every non-empty subset of Y has an inverse image, there isn't some $x \in X$ that doesn't map onto a $y \in Y$.

I realize I must be missing something pretty simple but I can't see what it is.  Can someone show me this part of the proof?

Comment: It’s a function:  every point in the domain must go to *some* point in the codomain.

Comment: I don't understand your argument for the necessitiy part. Anyway, if $f:X \to Y$ is onto and $B\subseteq Y$ is not empty there is $y\in B$ and, by the surjectivity, there is $x\in X$ with $f(x)=y\in B$ so that $x\in f^{-1}(B)$. Vice versa, for every $y\in Y$, the singleton $B=\{y\}$ is not empty and every $x\in f^{-1}(\{y\})$ satisfies $f(x)=y$ so that $f$ is onto.

Comment: @jochen, This may betray a deeper misunderstanding on my part, but why does the fact that every $x \in f^{-1}(\{y\})$ satisfies $f(x)=y$, establish that $f$ is onto.  Couldn't there still be some $x \in X$ where $f(x)$ is undefined or not a member of Y?

Comment: No. The definition of a function $f:X\to Y$ implies that *every* $x\in X$ is mapped to a unique value $f(x)$ *belonging to* $ Y$.

Comment: @Jochen, right, but isn't the existence of $f$ what you have to prove to establish the "sufficient" part of Halmos's statement?  I.e., doesn't the "sufficient" part mean that you can prove that $f:X->Y$ must exist from the fact that the inverse map of any $B \subseteq Y$ is a non-empty subset of X?

Comment: Is what I'm missing simply that the existence of the inverse image, i.e. $f^{-1}(\{y\})$, implies the existence of $f(x)$ with dom $X$ that is to $Y$?  And so the only question is whether that function is "onto", which your proof establishes.

Comment: The map $f:X\to Y$ is given from the outset.

Answer (score 1):

If $f:X\to Y$ is a surjection (i.e $X$ onto $Y$), for every $y\in Y$ there must exist a $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. That is,

$$
\forall y\in Y, \exists x\in X, f(x)=y
$$

Now, let us assume that $f: X\to Y$ is a function such that $B\subseteq Y$ implies $f^{-1}(B)\neq \varnothing$.

Necessary part:

If there exists a subset $B\subseteq Y$ such that $f^{-1}(B)= \varnothing$, every $y\in B\in Y$ would not be in the range of $f$ because no $f(x)$ maps to it.

Sufficient part:

If the inverse image $f^{-1}(B)$ of any subset $B$ is indeed nonempty, then we could just consider $\{y\}$ for every $y\in Y$ because then $\{y\}\subseteq Y$: For every $\{y\}$ there exists a nonempty subset $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ of $X$ containing the elements that map to $y$. Since $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is nonempty, we can simply obtain an element from the set, which surely maps to $y$ by virtue of it being contained in $f^{-1}(\{y\})$.

Therefore, as long as the inverse image $f^{-1}(B)$ of every subset $B\subseteq Y$ is nonempty, $f$ is a surjection.